# Неравномерная скорость анимации

Tags: css, css3, css-animation

Чтобы увидеть проблему, нужно взглянуть на анимацию. Ничего страшного, Суть в том, чтобы перед тем, как картинка исчезла и с конца передвинулась на своё место, была одинаковая скорость.

https://jsfiddle.net/ysggq4pf/

Получается так: картинки двигаются налево. После того, как появляются в конце, начинают двигаться медленнее.

```css
@keyframes c1 {
  13.5% { left: -252px; }
  13.6% { left: 800px; }
  to { left: 0; }
}
@keyframes c2 {
  27% { left: -252px; }
  27.1% { left: 930px; }
  to { left: 255px; }
}
@keyframes c3 {
  40.5% { left: -252px; }
  40.6% { left: 1060px; }
  to { left: 510px; }
}
@keyframes c4 {
  54% { left: -252px; }
  54.1% { left: 1190px; }
  to { left: 765px; }
}
@keyframes c5 {
  67.5% { left: -252px; }
  67.6% { left: 1320px; }
  to { left: 1020px; }
}

div {
  border: 1px black solid;
  position: relative;
}

a img {
  width: 250px;
}

.q1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  animation: c1 14s linear infinite;
}
.q2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 255px;
  animation: c2 14s linear infinite;
}
.q3 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 510px;
  animation: c3 14s linear infinite;
}
.q4 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 765px;
  animation: c4 14s linear infinite;
}
.q5 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 1020px;
  animation: c5 14s linear infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a href="#"> <img src="images/img_1.jpg" alt="Lions" class="q1"> </a>
  <a href="#"> <img src="images/img_2.jpg" alt="Lions" class="q2"> </a>
  <a href="#"> <img src="images/img_3.jpg" alt="Lions" class="q3"> </a>
  <a href="#"> <img src="images/img_4.jpg" alt="Lions" class="q4"> </a>
  <a href="#"> <img src="images/img_5.jpg" alt="Lions" class="q5"> </a>
</div>
```